# Shell script on Jenkins Execute Shell not working as expected

Tags: shell, jenkins

Here is the script on jenins execute shell , if the choice parameter selected as QA I'd like the script to execute ./runTest_qa.sh and otherwise run ./runTest_rnd.sh

```
a=$ENV
b=QA

if [ "$a" == 'QA' ]
then
   echo "Running the test on $ENV Env"
   chmod 777 ./runTest_qa.sh
   
   bash runTest_qa.sh $TestName $UserID
else
   echo "Running the test on $ENV Env"
   chmod 777 ./runTest_rnd.sh
   bash runTest_rnd.sh $TestName $UserID
  
fi
```

It always goes to the else statement  executes rnd script rather that QA

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: If your shell is `dash` then you need to test with `[ "$a" = 'QA' ]`, but you should also get an error. Is `ENV` set to `QA`? And you could move the `echo` statement before the if-case since they're the same. I doubt you need full permissions on both scripts, but that's a different issue...

Comment: Beware of unquoted variables `$TestName`, `$UserID`.